# segmentation fault in binary search tree

Tags: segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

```
/*
Here is the piece of code causing segmentation fault
*/

int search_for_data(T_NODE head, int data){
    while(head){
        if( head->data > data)
            head = head->left;
        if( head->data < data)
            head = head->right;
        else
            return head->key;
      }
return -999999;// in case the node is not found
}
```

The code seems to be throwing segmentation fault for few values but works fine for others. I tried searching for 22 and there was segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is missing `else` before `if`:

```
    if( head->data > data)
        head = head->left;
    else if( head->data < data) /* this line */
        head = head->right;
    else
        return head->key;
```

With the original code it evaluated the first `if` and then immediately the second, although `head` might have become `NULL` after the first `if`.

Comment: Thanx a lot!!
That was really helpful!